# Application of Cauchy Integral theorem

Tags: integration

Solve $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R} (2z^2+z-1) \left(\frac{A'(z)}{A(z)+3}\right)dz$$ where $$ A(z) =  z^{10} + 2z^9 + z^5 + 1$$

How to proceed with this question? Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: $$(A(z)+3)'\equiv A'(z)$$, so it may help you to set $A(z)=z^{10}+2z^9+z^5+4$ so you just have $\frac{A'(z)}{A(z)}$

Comment: The fraction is not dividing properly to give poles so that Cauchy Integral theorem is applicable. Could you please advise.